# GraphMethodException: errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, when using latest Firebase UI Auth release

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase UI (Facebook, Google & E-mail), I was using this dependency for Firebase UI:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
```

But there was a bug so I had to change to:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.0'
```

As it was solved in that release, but when I changed it to that version, it now works on my physical phone only but doesn't work on any emulator (I'm afraid it may not work on other phones), it shows a progress bar only

Now when I run the app using `4.3.0` I get the below error when I use `4.1.0` it works fine, but there are other bugs in `4.1.0` so I can't use it.

Here is the error from the Log:

> GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'MY_APP_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%7D)

So does anyone knows why am I getting this response or how to solve it? I think this response should occur if I'm requesting user information, but I'm not requesting any user information, my App Id is the only thing added and being requested.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?